# Selenium : How to check whether second tab is loaded completly

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

We are using selenium for automation. We need to launch 2 URLs simultaneously.
I am using driver.get to load first URL , which has in-built synchronization for page load. To load second window , I am using code below -

```js
String jscript="window.open('"+strURL+"')";
js.executeScript(jscript);
```

It works fine on chrome but on Edge , page takes time to load and when I try to do switchwindow to another window using title , it does not find window with that title.

if I add wait , then window loads and switchwindow works perfectly. 
I don't want to use hardcoded wait .How  I can check whether 2nd window is loaded completly?

I tried below , but it gives permission error on Edge-

```js
String jscript="var win=window.open('"+strURL+"');win.onload=function(){}";
js.executeScript(jscript);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to check whether page is loaded or not properly.

```
wait.until( new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
            public boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
            }
        }
    );
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi Tried using readystate before and it didn't work.It always returned complete.May be because window-1 is loaded sucessfully and unless we do switchwindow , it will show readystate of previous window. Since title is taking some time to get loaded  for window-2, I am not able to do switchwindow.

Comment: Try to switch on second tab using index if you have 2 tabs and then you can try this solution after switch.